# Ubuntu 14.04 lost cores on AMD CPU

Tags: boot, 14.04, cpu, amd-processor

It seems that I have a problem. Installed 14.04 a few days ago, everything was smooth sailing until yesterday it wouldn't boot up. Recovery mode says that CPU's 1-6 don't respond. After 7 it moves forward but then reboots. A live system from a USB stick boots up, just, and shows only one cpu present in /sys/devices/system/cpu.

What makes this really interesting is that all the while Windows 7 installed alongside seems to work just fine with all cores.

Any help, suggestions and ideas would be appreciated, thank you.

Output of `/proc/cpuinfo`:

> processor       : 0
>       vendor_id       : AuthenticAMD
>       cpu family      : 21
>       model           : 2
>       model name      : AMD FX(tm)-8320 Eight-Core Processor
>       stepping        : 0
>       microcode       : 0x600081c
>       cpu MHz         : 1400.000
>       cache size      : 2048 KB
>       physical id     : 0
>       siblings        : 1
>       core id         : 0
>       cpu cores       : 1
>       apicid          : 16
>       initial apicid  : 0
>       fpu             : yes
>       fpu_exception   : yes
>       cpuid level     : 13
>       wp              : yes
>       flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb arat cpb hw_pstate npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold bmi1
>       bogomips        : 7023.26
>       TLB size        : 1536 4K pages
>       clflush size    : 64
>       cache_alignment : 64
>       address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
>       power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb eff_freq_ro

And lshw http://pastebin.com/x1w3PSu6

Comment: As far as I can see all the other similar cases can boot up. I can't, which kind of makes it all the more difficult.

Comment: BIOS looks fine to me, also kern.log seems to say SMP is OK. The entire log here: http://pastebin.com/qTRy3bKJ

Comment: ACPI is enabled. Tried disabling and re-enabling it, no help.

Comment: Did you use a USB hub -> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2084166&page=2&p=12356703#post12356703 ?

Comment: No, but I just disconnected everything and now it works... Thank you very much for pointing that out.Now could someone please explain how having a joystick connected to a usb port can disable processor cores, and what could I do to prevent that from happening.